# Write proper documentation with ex_doc in Elixir

Tags: elixir, documentation, phoenix-framework, ex-doc

I'm writing docs with [**ex_doc**](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_doc/readme.html) and it seems very nice, but I have a problem. When a function has a map as a parameter, it is written as "map" inside documentation. I want to display it as "params".

### Example

```rb
def login(conn, %{"email" => email, "password" => password}) do
  ...
end
```

...appears in documentation as:

```rb
login(conn, map)
```

I know I can write my function as:

```rb
def login(conn, %{"email" => email, "password" => password} = params) do
  ...
end
```

...to obtain:

```rb
login(conn, params)
```

...but this way I'll get an annoying warning saying that "params is unused", because I'm not using it inside my function.

Another option is to write my function as:

```rb
def login(conn, params)
def login(conn, %{"email" => email, "password" => password}) do
  ...
end
```

...but I don't want to write a useless line of code just to change the name of a parameter in documentation. Any ideas? Which one is the proper/best/cleanest way to accomplish this?

### Update

As suggested, i tried to use spec to solve the problem.

```rb
  @spec login(conn :: %Plug.Conn{}, params :: map()) :: any()
  def login(conn, %{"email" => email, "password" => password}) do
  ...
  end
```

But this is what i'm getting in docs

```rb
login(conn, map)
login(
conn :: %Plug.Conn{
adapter: term(),
assigns: term(),
before_send: term(),
body_params: term(),
cookies: term(),
halted: term(),
host: term(),
method: term(),
owner: term(),
params: term(),
path_info: term(),
path_params: term(),
port: term(),
private: term(),
query_params: term(),
query_string: term(),
remote_ip: term(),
req_cookies: term(),
req_headers: term(),
request_path: term(),
resp_body: term(),
resp_cookies: term(),
resp_headers: term(),
scheme: term(),
script_name: term(),
secret_key_base: term(),
state: term(),
status: term()
},
params :: map()
) :: any()
```

map is still there instead of params, and i don't think that showing all params in conn struct will help reading docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the argument name starts with `_`, it will be stripped from the documentation output and you won't get an unused variable warning. The following works for me:

```
def login(conn, %{"email" => email, "password" => password} = _params) do
  # ...
end
```

[image: ex_doc output]

Answer (score 2):

You should create [typespecs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/typespecs.html#content) for your functions:

```rb
@spec login(conn :: %Plug.Conn{}, params :: map()) :: any()
def login(conn, %{"email" => email, "password" => password}) do
  ...
end
```

Once the function has a `@spec` defined, the parameter names will be automatically taken from there.

---

*Sidenote:* although `@spec`s are not mandatory, any mature Elixir/Erlang  code is supposed to have them. The approach suggested above is *correct*, unlike doubling function clauses and/or assigning unused variables..

Comment: @spec login(conn :: %Plug.Conn{}, params :: map()) :: any()    will not show params in documentation. map is there again. In addition i'm getting a list of all params inside the conn struct, that is so horrible

Comment: 1. `@spec` indeed enforces `params` to appear in the documentation, you can prove it by reviewing any OS elixir library, like `Ecto`. 2. Define a type of `conn` as `map()` if you are more after the cute view, rather than correct behaviour.

Comment: Don't know why, but as i said map is still there instead of params

Comment: You might try with `%{"email": binary()}, %{"password": binary()}` as a type for `params`, which is even more expressive.